# Armazenar resultado do IF numa variável para usar posteriormente

Tags: php, variáveis, if, sintaxe, condição

Esse código está com erro quando eu vou chamar a variável `$os`:

```
$os = (if($status_os_cliente == "A"){
     echo "SIM";
} else{
    echo "NÃO";
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se quiser você pode armazenar o resultado da comparação na variável `$os`. Como o operador de atribuição é associativo para a direita, ele irá retornar um *boolean* com o resultado da comparação.

```
if ($os = $status_os_cliente == "A") {
    echo "SIM";
} else {
    echo "NÃO";
};
```

Com isso você guarda o resultado no if, não o que acontece dentro do loop. Para isso é preciso fazer a atribuição dentro do loop, como já apontado em outras respostas.

Answer (score 6):

Não precisa de um if normal basta um ternário

```
$os = $status_os_cliente == "A" ? 'SIM' : 'NÃO';
echo $os;
```

Answer (score 6):

Se você quer ter uma variável com um valor que é definido condicionalmente você não pode definir esse valor com um `if`, você tem duas alternativas: uma é usar o operador condicional, que alguns chamam erradamente de ternário, ele tem uma condição e dois valores, um que será usado se a condição for verdadeira e outro se ela for falsa, desta forma pode usar com o está demonstrando, mas claro que a sintaxe é diferente; a outra é usar um `if` para controlar o fluxo, e é para isso que o `if` serve mesmo, aí em vez de escolher um valor escolhe como atribuir o valor, então você terá duas atribuições, uma com um valor e outra com outro valor.

```
$os = $status_os_cliente == "A" ? "SIM" : "NÃO";
echo $os;
```

É completamente desnecessário fazer com `if`, mas pode:

```
if ($status_os_cliente == "A") {
    $os = "SIM";
} else {
    $os = "NÃO";
}
echo $os;
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/E9oh3E). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/owxvullc-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Syntax/Conditional.php).

Eu diria que a forma com o `if` neste caso está conceitualmente errada, embora não faça diferença prática alguma. Há quem discorde já que depende de interpretação. Depende se você está considerando que está selecionando valores (operador) ou está selecionando ações (controle de fluxo).

Comment: mas eu poderia fazer com if? queria saber como por um if na variavel

Answer (score 3):

O erro é porque você está tentando atribuir um valor à variável `$os` mas dentro do if/else você manda imprimir um texto em tela (`echo`).

Caso queira manter a estrutura completa, como na pergunta, utiliza assim:

```
if($status_os_cliente == "A"){
   $os = "SIM";
} else{
   $os = "NÃO";
}
```

Mas como o pessoal falou nas respostas acima, o `if` ternário resolve o problema com menos código:

```
$os = $status_os_cliente == "A" ? "SIM" : "NÃO";
```

Answer (score 1):

Pode fazer nas duas formas, tanto com IF e ELSE quanto ternário, vou colocar as duas alternativas

```
if ($status_os_cliente == "A"){
  $os = "SIM";
} else{
  $os = "NÃO";
}
```

Ternário como os amigos já mostraram acima, ficará desta forma, mais simples e prático creio. Onde indica que se o valor recebido foi A, ele irá mostrar "SIM",  e caso contrário irá mostrar "NÃO"

```
$os = $status_os_cliente == "A" ? "SIM" : "NÃO";
echo $os;
```